# Delphi 10.1: How to get JSON string stored in the body parameter of a REST request (TCustomRESTRequest.Body)?

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm implementing a REST client application which communicates with the Coinbase GDAX Trading API in the JSON format (www.coinbase.com and https://docs.gdax.com/#introduction). I'm facing a problem in signing REST request messages with POST. Signing REST request messages with GET is working fine. Mainly because GET messages don't have a body parameter, which would be part of the signature when available. And this body parameter drives me crazy :-) I'm struggling to get the JSON string stored in the body parameter of a REST request (TCustomRESTRequest.Body). I need this JSON string to sign the REST request message properly. If I pass the body JSON string outside of TCustomRESTRequest.Body (ugly workaround), I get HTTP error 400 (bad request) with additional information "invalid signature". I assume the JSON string in TCustomRESTRequest.Body is somehow altered from the original JSON string. What I would like to achieve is to read out the JSON string directly from TCustomRESTRequest.Body, and then do the signing.

All the authentication and signing I'm doing in my class TCoinbaseAuthenticator (which is inherited from TCustomAuthenticator), or more specific in the DoAuthenticate method:

```
procedure TCoinbaseAuthenticator.DoAuthenticate(ARequest: TCustomRESTRequest); 
var 
  DateTimeUnix: Int64; 
  DateTimeUnixStr: string; 
  Sign: string; 
  HttpMethod: string; 
  BodyStr: string; 
begin 
  inherited; 

   ARequest.Params.BeginUpdate; 
   try 
     DateTimeUnix := DateTimeToUnix(TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now)); 
     DateTimeUnixStr := IntToStr(DateTimeUnix); 

     HttpMethod := HttpMethodToString(ARequest.Method); 

     // BodyStr := ARequest.Body ... << here I'm strugging to get the JSON string 

     Sign := GenerateSignature(DateTimeUnixStr, HttpMethod, '/' + ARequest.Resource, BodyStr); 

     ARequest.AddAuthParameter('CB-ACCESS-KEY', FAPIKey, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]); 
     ARequest.AddAuthParameter('CB-ACCESS-SIGN', Sign, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]); 
     ARequest.AddAuthParameter('CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP', DateTimeUnixStr, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]); 
     ARequest.AddAuthParameter('CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE', FAPIPassphrase, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]); 
     ARequest.AddAuthParameter('CB-VERSION', '2015-07-22', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]); 
     ARequest.AddAuthParameter('Content-Type', 'application/json', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]); 
   finally 
     ARequest.Params.EndUpdate; 
  end; 
end;
```

Here is my signature generating function (I think the code is ok, because it works fine if I don't have to consider the body parameter, e.g. for GET requests):

```
function TCoinbaseAuthenticator.GenerateSignature(ATimeStamp: string; AMethod: string; AURL: string; ABody: string): string; 
var 
  s: string; 
  SignStr: string; 
  BitDigest: T256BitDigest; 
  key: string; 
begin 
  s := ATimeStamp+AMethod+AURL+ABody; 
  key := MimeDecodeString(FAPISecret); 
  BitDigest := CalcHMAC_SHA256(key, s); 
  SignStr := SHA256DigestAsString(BitDigest); 
  SignStr := MimeEncodeStringNoCRLF(SignStr); 
  Result := SignStr; 
end;
```

Some more insights of the Coinbase (GDAX) message signing process:

All REST requests must contain the following headers: 
CB-ACCESS-KEY: The api key as a string (created by Coinbase) 
CB-ACCESS-SIGN: The base64-encoded signature 
CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: A timestamp for your request 
CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE: The passphrase you specified when creating the API key

The CB-ACCESS-SIGN header is generated by creating a sha256 HMAC using the base64-decoded secret key on the prehash string timestamp + method (GET,POST, etc.) + requestPath + body (where + represents string concatenation) and base64-encode the output. The timestamp value is the same as the CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP header.

The body is the request body string or omitted if there is no request body (typically for GET requests).

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: What charset does `CalcHMAC_SHA256()` use when generating the hash for string data? `UnicodeString` is natively UTF-16 but is typically not *transmitted* as UTF-16. JSON is typically UTF-8 instead. That would explain the "invalid signature" error if you use the wrong charset.

Comment: Guido, did you figure this one out eventually?  Struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your comment, Remy! I did indeed use the wrong charset for the signature calculation. So at least my super ugly workaround (passing the body JSON string outside of TCustomRESTRequest.Body into the authenticator class) is working.

For the first part of the problem I don't think there is an easy solution. I got some support from Embarcadero which I would like to share with others who have a similar problem.

*Looking at the TBody class, which is used for the Body property, this looks like it only has properties to write to - there isn't anything that will help in reading it back. I found that if I added a body to a TRequest, this created a TRestRequestParameter with a name of body. I would therefore suggest that you can get to it via RestRequest1.Params.ParameterByName('body');*

Unfortunately this proposal is not working. Reason:

The parameter "body" is stored in the body request parameter list (TCustomRESTRequest.FBody.FParams), and not in RESTRequest parameter list (TCustomRESTRequest.Params). Since TCustomRESTRequest.FBody.FParams doesn't have a public property, I cannot access the field from outside. Later the parameters are copied from TCustomRESTRequest.FBody.FParams to TCustomRESTRequest.Params, but this is too late in my case, because the authenticator (where I calculate the signature) is called earlier. Meaning in my TCoinbaseAuthenticator.DoAuthenticate(ARequest: TCustomRESTRequest) method the parameter list in ARequest is still empty.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this ?
I'm writing to RESTRequest.AddBody() in one part of my code and need to read back the value elsewhere, but although a Body param is created, it seems to have an empty value.

e.g simple test gives a value for all params except for the one of Kind = pkREQUESTBODY

   for I := 0 to RESTRequest.params.count-1 do
      Showmessage(RESTRequest.params[i].value);